# Using a 12V DC adapter to power Arduino nano, 12v Solenoid and an Hygrometer

Tags: sensors, power, arduino-nano

First of all I am very novice in electronics so bare with me.

I am trying to make a self watering system using arduino nano, first I tried the fly fish hygrometer module with the 5V power of the Arduino, and that worked.

Then I wanted to add the 12V solenoid, so I changed to a 12V external power through the Vin.

My goal is to use only one power source.

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

And Schematics [image]

My question is:

**Can I power the hygrometer module using for the positive the 5V outlet of the Arduino nano and the ground from the 12V power source as shown in the figures?**

Or will this burn the module or screw the readings?

Comment: yes the 5v out can run the module (hygrometers use next to nothing), although 12v is a little high for the nano, might get warm. but no worries, she'll be alright mate.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis, but my question is that if you see the schematics, the + of the hygro goes to the 5v and the ground goes to the 12V is that ok?

Comment: you mean 0v? that's fine, all grounds are typically commoned (connected together so they have continuity)